# Why do I get property 'map' is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service like this:

```
public getUsers() {
  return this.httpClient.get(environment.BASE_URL + `api/all`);
}
```

And in component, I set the user to the ngx-bootstrap table

```
import { Component, OnInit, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { UserService } from "./service.service";
import { IUser } from "./users.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "app-users",
  templateUrl: "./users.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./users.component.css"]
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  allUsers: IUser[];
  page = 1;
  pageSize = 4;
  collectionSize: any;
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      this.collectionSize = data.length;
      this.allUsers = data;
    });
  }
  get users(): IUser[] {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    return this.allUsers.map((user, i) => ({ id: i + 1, ...user 
    })).slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize 
    + this.pageSize);
  }
}
```

I always get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

I tried to use `.pipe()`, but then I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined`

In my DOM I get all data in the table, but only I have this error in console.

Comment: Your Users Data is undifined

Comment: i would say that you are trying to call `users()` before getting the result of the subscription to `userService.getUers()`. As it's an asynchronous call, you need to wait the get the result to populate `this.allUsers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding one extra line shortest possible solution for this could be initialize `allUsers` when you define them so simply change

```
allUsers: IUser[];
```

to

```
allUsers: IUser[]=[];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to initialize `allUsers` variable before you assign data:

```
this.allUsers = [];
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because getters in Angular are reevaluated every time the change detection occurs. As `allUsers` is populated asynchronously, there is some time when it's undefined. That's why you get that error.

One possible solution is to initialize `allUsers` as an empty array so it will never be undefined.

```
this.allUsers = [];
```

Bear in mind that this code will run every time the change detection occurs:

```
return this.allUsers.map((user, i) => ({ id: i + 1, ...user 
 })).slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize 
+ this.pageSize);
}
```

Do you really need it to run like that? Doing the mapping every time change detection occurs. If no, you can optimize it by not using a getter for `users` and instead create the global `users` variable (like you did for `allUsers`) and do the mapping inside the `this.userService.getUsers()` callback.

Answer (score 2):

## To complete maryrio7 answer

You are making an asynchronous call to your API. That means that your fetching can take a long time. While your call is processing, `this.allUsers` remains `undefined`.
It's why you get this error.

In a second time, when your asynchronous operation is done, `this.allUsers`is full and the change detection on the reference is performing. That explains why you get all your data in the table. But the error also occured before.