# Observable table not updated after added new item

Tags: angular, ngrx

I make simple CRUD app for exercise and I have problem with update table automatically.

I call data from API, and also post new data to API. 
In-app I showing table list with ng-bootstrap, and for add new item I use the bootstrap modal box.

In my `service` here is my code for geting all users and add new user

```
getUsers(): Observable<UserModel[]> {
return this.httpClient.get<UserModel[]>(environment.BASE_URL + this.apiurlAllUsers).pipe(
  tap(data => console.log(data)),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
}


updateUser(formData) {
this.httpClient.post(environment.BASE_URL + "user/add/", formData)
.subscribe(response => this.getUsers(), error => console.log(error));
}
```

and here is code from `user.component`

```
getUsersInList() {
this.allUsers = [];
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
  this.collectionSize = data.length;
  this.allUsers = data;
});
}

//passing formData from modal box to service

modalRef.result
  .then(result => {
    this.userService.updateUser(result);
  })
  .catch(error => {});
}
```

After a refreshing page, new data is in a table, but how to get it without refresh?
Pls if someone can me explain what Im doing wrong?
Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your service method to return observable

```
updateUser(formData) {
 return this.httpClient.post(environment.BASE_URL + "user/add/", formData);
}
```

then in users component

```
modalRef.result
  .then(result => {
    this.userService.updateUser(result).subscribe((data)=>{
    this.getUsersInList()
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {});
}
```

Also remove `this.allUsers = [];` from your getUsersInList bcs it will empty the list and ui will show blank page until data loaded

Comment: here I get `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'`

Comment: @Arter bcs it's bcs you didn't use return keyword in your service method.make sure it should be `return this.httpClient.post(environment.BASE_URL + "user/add/", formData);` instead of `this.httpClient.post(environment.BASE_URL + "user/add/", formData);`

Comment: @Arter glad it helped

Comment: one question about  `this.allUsers = [];`... if I remove thisI get `UsersComponent.html:19 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` ...here is my question about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131100/why-do-i-get-property-map-is-undefined

Comment: @Arter use `allUsers: IUser[]=[];` instead of `allUsers: IUser[];`

Answer (score 1):

Don't subscribe in the service. Return an observable from your `updateUser()` method (which should be named `createUser()` or `addUser()`, BTW). Then use `switchMap()` in the component to list the users again once you know the creation has succeeded:

```
from(modalRef.result).pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.userService.createUser(result)),
  switchMap(() => this.userService.getUsers())
).subscribe(users => this.allUsers = users);
```

Also, don't use `any`. Define a `User` interface descirbing the structure of a User and use it. And don't store `collectionSize`, since you can obtain it simply from `allUsers.length`: it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `async` pipe to get the request result to the UI.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of getUsers() | async"> ...
```

Comment: When using async pipe u don't need to subscribe from the component. Angular do that for u. So remove the getUser logic from the component.